# Integrating a Flash game into an existing application

Tags: ios, objective-c, flash, actionscript, integration

I have a game developed in Flash and Actionscript 3 that someone else is interested in integrating into their iPad app, which is written in Objective-C. The idea is to be able to run the game within their iPad app.

Our Flash game can be run standalone on the iPad using the export-to-iOS feature of Flash, and we have a number of apps that we've authored in Flash and released on the iPad using this method. This is an easy way to deploy to Web or iPad using a common codebase.

However, we've never had to deal with integrating these games into other iOS applications that are written in Objective-C.

Is there any way to do something like this? I can think of a couple of possibilities:

1. Export the Flash game to a compiled "object file" (like swc) that can be linked into the Objective-C application
2. Embed the ipa of the Flash game into the other application

Are either of these options, or another option I haven't considered, possible technically at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, 2. is certainly not possible. You can't execute anything from inside app sandbox (even though, technically, you could embed a binary into .app package).

Even 1. is not possible, since you can't export to framework from Flash. Although, if you're using Adobe AIR, there is a workaround, you can embed native code into your AIR application. ([Details](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)). According to [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/using-ane-in-flash.html), you can even embed ANEs into Flash application.

Hope this helps!